# Normal force on a person

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I recently solved a exercise based on normal force ( given at the end of page in link: https://openoregon.pressbooks.pub/bodyphysics/chapter/the-normal-force/).

I want to understand why the normal force will be larger than weight of person when he is jumping and when he is landing after jumping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Earth, providing a exerting an upward normal force of 1g is what is required to support something vertically. By support I mean neither falling nor rising.

In the case of someone jumping, the normal force must produce an upward acceleration on the person that not only supports the person's weight but overcomes that weight to accelerate them upwards.

In the case of someone falling and hitting the ground, you must not only support the person's weight, you must provide extra force to produce an upward acceleration to reduce their downward velocity to zero.

The case of someone both jumping or falling and hitting the ground are both cases where an upward acceleration is applied to them. The only difference is the initial and final velocities. More acceleration means more force required.

Comment: so while jumping we want to go  upwards and want something to make us go upwards. we do this by pressing the ground making it exert more reaction force on us thus normal > weight and as you said that more higher we want to jump more acceleration we require and therefore harder we press the ground and harder the ground pushes us

Comment: @lalittolani Yes. In both cases where you start a jump up or stop a downard fall, you are trying to change the velocity upward (aka apply an upward acceleration) and in both cases you have to support the weight of the object (so it doesn't fall through the floor) while also producing that upward acceleration. Together this is requires an acceleration upward greather than 1g (greater than the weight of the object).

Answer (score 1):

A force is mass multiplied with acceleration, $F=m \cdot a$, and acceleration is change of velicity. You need an additional acceleration to jump off the ground (this is the pressing yourself off the ground). Also at landing, you hit the ground with some velocity and decelerate. The larger the velocity you are landing with and the shorter the time in which this velocity is reduced to zero, the larger the  force is. This is why you break your legs when jumping from a tree or building and why it's a good idea to go into knee (making  time span for deceleration longer).

Comment: therefore assuming that time intervals in which are velocity is reduced to zero are not very different, the larger the velocity we have, the larger the retardation we require  , therefore larger an upward force required

Answer (score 0):

*The normal force acting on a jumping person is* **zero**, as there is no surface to "support him." (As is the correct answer to the link)

*When the person is landing after the jump:* intuitively, imagine
you are jumping off a short roof top and when you land on your two feet it is as if your body is still trying to go down. The Earth, a rigid body, prevents you from going down any further.

Newton's $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ law,
$$
  \sum F = ma
$$
the acceleration $a=a_y=0$ (assuming the $+y$ direction to be downward). The sum on the left is,
$$
  \sum F = f + mg - n
$$
If $n$ were to be equal to only $mg$ then you would fall through the Earth due to $f$, which clearly is not the case. Therefore, $n= mg + f>mg$.

But what is $f$? It is probably a few things, but it is mainly gravity,
$$
  F_g = G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}
$$